# Which algorithms do you advise to learn first

Tags: algorithm

I have started programming few years ago.
and generally i use for programming C or C#.
and now i want to learn some algorithms.
to learn and to teach my friends.

so which algorithms do you advise for beginners?

Comment: Algorithms for ?? Be more specific, please

Comment: general algorithms for beginners

Comment: ok then, you could refer to Peladao's post - sort and search algorithms - there're lots of them, you' have a lot to read and try (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is a book set about algorithms in general ->
[Art of Computer Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321751043)

Comment: Great reference, but good luck getting through that as a beginner. I don't recommend this one unless you have a solid computer science background.

Answer (score 7):

Algorithms for searching and sorting are usually used first in teaching algorithms to CS students. So you may want to start there.

For instance, see [Sorting Algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm).

Comment: I was about to write the same. There's a good selection of algorithms in the wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms

Comment: I was just adding the same link :)

Comment: I wouldn't really restrict yourself to one particular area. Finding a good book covering few general topics seems like a better idea.

Answer (score 3):

Subscribe at Projet Euler, tons of original algorithm, teaching you a lot of optimisation.

http://projecteuler.net/

Comment: @Benoit : thank you ex-teammate, what's your score ? 191/322 for the moment

Comment: Actually I don't go to ProjectEuler much. But your answer is a good answer for the OP. Does your first name begin with a C?

Answer (score 0):

You may already started many years ago, do you remember how [long division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division) works?

for more normal compsci stuff perhaps [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort), its simple, and unlike [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) a bit more useful

Answer (score 0):

Going to add algorithms concerning trees and, more generally, [graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) to the list. They are everywhere in programming, learning to recognize and exploit them is crucial to efficiently solve a large amount of problems (maybe even the majority of all problems programmers encounter).